# cancelling $http request angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Trying to cancel an $http request on a search input box but the prior requests don't seem to be getting aborted.  I followed the example from other stack overflow questions.  Here is my JS code:

```
var canceler;
$scope.someFunction = function() {
      if(canceler)
         canceler.resolve();
      canceler = $q.defer();
      $http({method: 'GET', url:  service+url, timeout: canceler.promise}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-change="someFunction" />
```

If I enter two characters into the search box the function is called twice but the initial request still goes through.  So both requests end up going through and pending on the response time it is random which response is being used.  Did the library change at some point?  I had this working awhile ago but now it no longer is working.

Comment: I think your approach is incorrect, you shouldn't be spamming your server and cancelling requests whenever the input changes. Instead, do  a timeout and send a request when the user stops typing (e.g. whenever  the input changes, set a 200ms timeout to contact the server, whenever the input changes clear the timeout and create a new one) – this is how it's usually done.

Comment: MMM is right, but this should still work as expected (even if it is not a good practice).

Comment: I will change my approach then and see if that resolves the issue I am having.

Comment: I updated to do that and it seems to remove the issue I was having.  However I feel like a cleaner solution would involve both incase the first request takes significantly longer than the second it may load the first request rather than the second if a user types slower than the timeout.

Comment: Mmm... this post is recent and seems to use same approach as you, maybe missing some detail? Check this link: Cancelling $http Requests in AngularJS

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think there might be something wrong with the version of angular js cause they have removed the timeout option for promise and you can now only give timeout in milliseconds but there is a work around for that,
check this link
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2624-aborting-an-ajax-request-in-angularjs-using-httpi.htm