# Cancelling Requests AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, request, response, laravel-5

I'm wondering if it's possible to manage the following scenario:

I'm using Laravel as API and AngularJS as Frontend. I have a functionality which allows to the user to search over a list of customers. But I'm experiencing a problem because when user enters every letter of the name of the customer, I'm sending a request to Laravel (API), but sometimes the last request is getting the response faster than the first request.

So, the final result displayed to the user is the response of the first request, which is bad because the user has already finished to type the entire customer name.

My objective is this:

1. If the user types the first letter, send a request to the API.
2. If the user types a second letter, check if the previous response is not received then cancell the previous request and send a new request.
3. If the user types a third letter, check if a response was received from the second request then send a request, if the previous response is not received then cancell the previous request and send a new request.

I'm not sure if my example is clear, but have seen similar behaviour before on many websites.

If found this: [Cancelling $http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915513/cancelling-http-request-angularjs) but looks like this is a bad practice.

How can I do this? Any clue will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be met quite easily by setting a boolean variable to true right before the API call is started, and setting it to false when it responds. And then you can use this variable to check if a request is already in progress.

However, I think what you want is actually a little different than what you describe. It makes more sense to wait until the user stops typing before sending the request. In Angular you can do that quite easily with the debounce setting:

```
<input ng-model="params.q" ng-change="doApiCall()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" type="text">
```

Edit: I now see that your requirement is a little bit different. You want to cancel the running request. There may be ways to cancel running ajax calls, but you certainly can't guarantee that. What should be doable is to make a queue so that the new request will start right after the last one is finished.

Comment: Thanks @wvdz Your answer is really helpful, and I'm not sure if my requirement is a good practice as I said regarding to the link provided.

Comment: However, your solution works fine! It's really easy to use... I think this is perfect for my needs! Thanks.